# Why doesn't my program have any output?

Tags: java, character

```
public class miscellaneous2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        long a=System.currentTimeMillis();
        long b=a%100;
        if(b>64&&b<90)
            System.out.println(" "+(char)b);
        else if(b<21)
            System.out.println(" "+(char)(b+65));
        else if(b>=21&&b<=44)
            System.out.println(" "+(char)(b+44));
        else if(b>44&&b<65)
            System.out.println(" "+(char)(b+21));

    }
}
```

I tried to show random Uppercase Letter. Why sometimes I get empty output?

Comment: Why don't you try another experiment - what happens when your output all of the characters in the range of 0-100?  You might find some "empty" characters in there (which is probably more like [non-printable ascii](http://web.itu.edu.tr/~sgunduz/courses/mikroisl/ascii.html) )

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused of what you are attempting. Is 'char' an array? If so your syntax is off, you should do this

```
 System.out.println(" "+char[b+65]);
 System.out.println(" "+char[b+44]);
```

Comment: No, my guess would be that the OP is using ASCII values (hence the 21,44,65; those correspond to specific ASCII characters). Besides, I'm 99.9% sure you can't name an array 'char' in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this with the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class.  You can specify an exact range.

```
System.out.println((char) (new Random().nextInt(26) + 65));
```

`nextInt(26)` returns a random number between 0-25

`+ 65` bumps that numbers up to start at 65 instead of 0

```
0 becomes 65
1 becomes 66
...
25 becomes 90
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you're using 4 ranges:

- [0,20]
- [21, 44]
- [45, 64]
- [65, 90]

*b* probably falls in the range [91, 99].